# Internal testing in Google Play doesn't send out emails

Tags: android, release-management, google-console-developer

I have successfully uploaded my `APK` to `Google Console` and set my own email adress as tester for internal testing. But when I Submit the app for internal testing I don't receive any mail. As you can see the email is correct and the `APK` has been uploaded correctly. Have I missed a step or done something wrong? Don't understand.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to share the opt-in link to your internal tester manually:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

> 8. Copy the "Opt-in URL" to share with your testers.

Once your tester have opted-in they will see the alpha/beta build on play store as soon as play store has published it.

Moreover the email addresses used should by the ones of the Google Account your testers use on their mobile phones.

> Step 3: Share your opt-in URL with users After you create a test,
>   you'll get a URL link to your app to share with your testers. The
>   opt-in link only shows when an app is "Published." Apps in "Draft" or
>   "Pending publication" won't show the opt-in link. After clicking the
>   opt-in link, your testers will get an explanation of what it means to
>   be a tester and a link to opt in. Each tester needs to opt in using
>   the link. If you're running a closed test with a Google Group or
>   Google+ Community, users need to join the group or community before
>   opting in to your test.

Comment: I see! I had no idea. Thanks a lot for that info! :)

Comment: Then what is the point of setting up the email lists - just to restrict who can install the app for testing?

Comment: @Dabbler exactly. You have to restrict your closed or internal test to a limited number of chosen users.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem and it turns out I created the internal release by hadn't published it I guess.

The solution was to click the "Create Release" button at the top of the internal test page under "App releases".  I hadn't clicked that button originally because I thought it would advance my app from internal release to release to the general public.  Basically I got confused by the label.

Comment: I am shocked at how confusing they make release management in Play Console. Apple TestFlight is so much easier 

Comment: Apple Test Flight automatically send an email every you add someone and their have a button to re-send invitation.